# Python Beginner question: Remove duplicate apps from dictionary - error: list index out of range

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing, append

I want to remove duplicate entries out of my dictionary and put them - if unique - into another "already-added"-list. But this error occurred. Can someone help me? Thanks, Nicolas

```
android_clean = [] 
already_added = []
for app in android:
    name = app[0]
    n_reviews = float(app[3])
    
    if (reviews_max[name] == n_reviews) and (name not in already_added):
        android_clean.append(app)
        already_added.append(name)

explore_data(android_clean,0,3,True)
```

*Error description:*

```
Number of rows: 0

IndexErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-8a2f24b7862c> in <module>()
----> 1 explore_data(android_clean,0,3,True)

<ipython-input-11-403f879c8933> in explore_data(dataset, start, end, rows_and_columns)
      7     if rows_and_columns:
      8         print('Number of rows:', len(dataset))
----> 9         print('Number of columns:', len(dataset[0]))
     10 
     11 print(android_header)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Please include `android`, `reviews_max` and `explore_data` in your code

Answer (score 0):

You have a hidden assumption that `dataset` must have data in it.
If dataset is empty, then dataset[0] will throw the IndexError as you're trying to fetch an item from an empty list

when you're calling `explore_data` function, your `rows_and_columns` is passed as a True (the last attribute), `explore_data(android_clean,0,3,True)`, thus, your if is actually `if True`
It should probably be like this:

```
if dataset:
    print('Number of rows:', len(dataset))
    print('Number of columns:', len(dataset[0]))
```

I would also utilise kwargs so you can have better visibility on what your sending to your functions

Comment: thanks @MenyIssakov. Where in my code above should I correct it? Do I have to define ```explore_data``` before like my dictionaries? Thanks for your time

Comment: I mean, if this condition `(reviews_max[name] == n_reviews) and (name not in already_added)` never evaluates to True, then you never add any app to `android_clean`, and you're passing an empty list to `explore_data` function.

You either need to change the if condition inside `explore_data` because it makes not sense, or don't always pass `True` value for `rows_and_columns`

Comment: I'm glad.
Would appreciate an Accepted Answer

Answer (score 0):

@MenyIssakov:
with "android" defined in an above code line:

```
android_clean = [] 
already_added = []

for app in android:
    name = app[0]
    n_reviews = float(app[3])
    
    if (reviews_max[name] == n_reviews) and (name not in already_added):
        android_clean.append(app)
        already_added.append(name)
        
explore_data(android_clean,0,3,True)
```